# How to access nested style control

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-10.2-tokyo, firemonkey-style

I have custom styled FireMonkey control. Its style contains several levels of nested controls.

I need to access those controls and change some style properties at run-time. To do that I am using `FindStyleResource<T>` method.

I have no problem in retrieving first level of controls inside style. But accessing controls on second level with `FindStyleResource` fails if control parent is descendant of `TStyledControl`.

Question is how to access those nested style controls regardless of their parent type?

**Style:**

```
object TStyleContainer
  object TLayout
    StyleName = 'MyHeader'
    Align = Center
    Size.Width = 100.000000000000000000
    Size.Height = 50.000000000000000000
    Size.PlatformDefault = False
    Visible = False
    TabOrder = 0
    object TLabel
      StyleName = 'title'
      Align = Client
      StyledSettings = [Style]
      Size.Width = 36.000000000000000000
      Size.Height = 50.000000000000000000
      Size.PlatformDefault = False
      TextSettings.HorzAlign = Center
      Text = 'Title'
    end
    object TLayout
      StyleName = 'green'
      Align = MostLeft
      Size.Width = 32.000000000000000000
      Size.Height = 50.000000000000000000
      Size.PlatformDefault = False
      object TPath
        StyleName = 'greenpath'
        Align = Fit
        Data.Path = {
          07000000000000000000404100000041010000000000C0400000604101000000
          B81EED405C8F76410100000000004041AE472D410100000052B884415C8F7641
          010000000000904100006041030000000000404100000041}
        Fill.Color = claGreen
        HitTest = False
        Size.Width = 32.000000000000000000
        Size.Height = 50.000000000000000000
        Size.PlatformDefault = False
        Stroke.Kind = None
        WrapMode = Fit
      end
    end
    object TSpeedButton
      StyleName = 'red'
      Align = MostRight
      Position.X = 68.000000000000000000
      Size.Width = 32.000000000000000000
      Size.Height = 50.000000000000000000
      Size.PlatformDefault = False
      object TPath
        StyleName = 'redpath'
        Align = Fit
        Data.Path = {
          07000000000000000000404100000041010000000000C0400000604101000000
          B81EED405C8F76410100000000004041AE472D410100000052B884415C8F7641
          010000000000904100006041030000000000404100000041}
        Fill.Color = claRed
        HitTest = False
        Size.Width = 32.000000000000000000
        Size.Height = 32.571426391601560000
        Size.PlatformDefault = False
        Stroke.Kind = None
        WrapMode = Fit
      end
    end
  end
end
```

**Control:**

```
type
  TMyHeader = class(TStyledControl)
  protected
    procedure ApplyStyle; override;
    function GetDefaultStyleLookupName: string; override;
   end;

procedure TMyHeader.ApplyStyle;
var
  LGreen: TLayout;
  LGreenPath: TPath;
  LRed: TSpeedButton;
  LRedPath: TPath;
begin
  inherited;
  if FindStyleResource<TLayout>('green', LGreen) then
    begin
      // following call will find greenpath control 
      if FindStyleResource<TPath>('greenpath', LGreenPath) then
        LGreenPath.Fill.Color := TAlphaColorRec.Blue;
    end;

  if FindStyleResource<TSpeedButton>('red', LRed) then
    begin 
      // following call will fail to find find redpath control  
      if FindStyleResource<TPath>('redpath', LRedPath) then
        LRedPath.Fill.Color := TAlphaColorRec.Blue;

      // this variant also fails
      if LRed.FindStyleResource<TPath>('redpath', LRedPath) then
        LRedPath.Fill.Color := TAlphaColorRec.Blue;
    end;
end;

function TMyHeader.GetDefaultStyleLookupName: string;
begin
  Result := 'MyHeader';
end;
```

Original style:

[image]

Changed style (only green arrow color was successfully changed)

[image]

In `ApplyStyle` method I can access `greenpath` from the style and change its color to blue. Hoewever, I cannot get `redpath` using `FindStyleResource` method.

Comment: Does the changes apply when call only the part to find redpath control?

Comment: I would suggest that you use `LRedPath:= FindStyleResource('redpath') as TPath; If Assigned(LRedPath) then ...`

Comment: @Sami No, redpath cannot be found in any combination. The only difference between failure and success is whether parent is descendant of TStyledControl or not.

Comment: @Sami Your suggestion does not change a thing since generic version of FindStyleResource calls nongeneric variant.

Answer (score 0):

The standard way to access style elements is via `TFMXObject` and iterate the children style objects.

Try this:

```
procedure TMyHeader.ApplyStyle;
var
  objFMX,
  inObjFMX: TFMXObject;
  LRed: TSpeedButton;
  LRedPath: TPath;
begin
  inherited;
  objFMX:=FindStyleResource('red');
  if assigned(objFMX) and (objFMX is TSpeedButton) then
  begin
    LRed:=objFMX as TSpeedButton;
    inObjFMX:=LRed.FindStyleResource('redpath');
    if assigned(inObjFMX) and (inObjFMX is TPath) then
    begin
      LRedPath:=inObjFMX as TPath;
     LRedPath.Fill.Color := TAlphaColorRec.Blue;
   end;
  end
end;
```

---

**Updated Code:** The `FindStyleResource` does not work in the above code. A different approach is followed below.

```
procedure TMyHeader.ApplyStyle;
var
  objFMX,
  inObjFMX: TFMXObject;
  LRedPath: TPath;
begin
  inherited;
  objFMX:=FindStyleResource('red');
  if assigned(objFMX) and (objFMX is TSpeedButton) then
  begin
    for inObjFMX in objFMX.Children do
    begin
      if inObjFMX is TPath then
      begin
        LRedPath:=inObjFMX as TPath;
        LRedPath.Fill.Color:=TAlphaColorRec.Blue;
        Break;
      end;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

That works on 10.2

Comment: I will have to check, but this is slight variation of my code that does not work. FindStyleResource cannot find redpath

Comment: Yep, this code suffers from same issue. FindStyleResource is broken.