# Is there a way to remove padding from the checkbox itself in FMX?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

What im trying to achive is that all components are aligned to the left ( red line )
But as you can see checkboxes and radiobuttons has some strange padding even tho padding itself is set to 0.

[image]

Can anyone help me with this one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seeing your tags I'm assuming you are using the FMX framework. This can be achieved by right clicking the Checkbox in design time > Click Edit Default Style > Click on the little box and set the "Align" property to left. The same applies to the radio button. Lastly close the Style Designer tab and click Yes to save the changes.

Comment: Yeah so i kinda need to do it in the code + it will only work with default style, right? I need to take to the account other styles too.

Comment: You'll need to access the style object directly then. By default it seems they dont have names but I could be wrong. See the following: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52478699/how-to-access-nested-style-control